# Getting Error OK as response from http post

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am making an api call to node server. Its a post call but I am getting error as response but the data on firebase changes.

```
const header : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/s/getKey', { seqKey : 'invoices' }, {
  headers : header
}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Update

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little more? example the `console.log` that information prints

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the error which you have got ??

Comment: Sounds like you node  server sends text response but Angular http client  by default uses json parser to parse response. If so addition of `responseType: 'text'` solve your problem

Comment: @Meet I added error screen shot

Comment: @JuanE.LondoñoT. control is not reaching to console.log

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I was using the Spring REST API on the backend which was just returning a String, which was a problem because Angular HttpClient expects JSON. I solved it by wrapping my String in a simple POJO and returned that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Handling your data properly after subscription helps you to have a good look at the response data. A better way would be to use the `map()`.

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/s/getKey', { seqKey : 'invoices' }, {
    headers : header
}).map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
}, error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an error interceptor that was catching the error, and rethrowing another error with just the message

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    
    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
                if ([401, 403].indexOf(err.status) !== -1) {
                    return this.HandleAuthenticationError(request, next);
                }

                // const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;

                // I was throwing error instead of err
                return throwError(() => err);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

For the people that will see this in the future, verify that the error injected by the post method is not modified before you access it

Answer (score -2):

i am not sure but may be your node server code written badly which is not returning error response properly, can you please post your node API code so that we can explore it